# Parse Midi Packet in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, midi, coremidi

I'm having a hard time parsing Midi Packets. At times its 3 bytes then it can be 155 bytes on one stream.
How can I iterate through the massive packet and just get what I need? 
Say for "b0" its only 3 bytes of 12 a byte packet, I just want to split "b0" and its following bytes:
[b02c2c] then the others [b02c2d] or [f0....] in the same packet...

Heres what I've been  working on and is giving me a headache..

```
NSString *StringFromPacket(const MIDIPacket *packet,id self)
{
    NSMutableString * result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < packet->length; i++)
    {   
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x",packet->data[i]];

        for (NSString *line in [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"b0"])
        {
            // This appends to string but b0 disappears and only get the following 2 bytes
            // Along with the others like f0,a0,90. I would like to filter without losing b0
            [result appendFormat:line];
        }
    }

    [self controlEvent:result];
}


-(void)controlEvent:(NSString *)line
{
    if (line == @"b02c2c")
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question and code -- can you show a few MIDI packets and what manipulations you want to make on them?

Comment: Do not use string-matching for parsing binary data. Make sure you fully understand the MIDI data format before using it.

Comment: I would basically receive a packet like this:
18 bytes: [b0,0c,0e,b0,2c,05,b0,0c,0f,b0,2c,02,b0,0c,0d,b0,2c,02]

How can I separate them into 3 bytes then send to a method?

Comment: Not all MIDI messages are 3 bytes long!  You should really look into the protocol more in depth.

Comment: What library are you using? It should provide higher level of control like midi event type and midi event value. There has to be such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with IPhone programming, but I had quick look at iOS MIDI API.

In MIDI there are various MIDI events (note on, note off, controller change, etc.) Each event can have different number of bytes. From first byte you can event type and from the type you know message length (see MIDI reference at http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php ) The only exception is System Exclusive MIDI message (for more details see MIDi reference and reference for specific device that can send and receive System Exclusive messages)

It seems that MIDIPacket can contain variable number of MIDI messages. So you can have look at first byte. Let's suppose you received a Note On midi event on MIDI channel 1. In first byte you will have value 80 (hex). From documentation you can see that Note On Event has two data bytes. Next byte is MIDI note number (you can see list of MIDI note numbers e.g. on http://midikits.net23.net/midi_analyser/midi_note_numbers_for_octaves.htm ). And the next note number is velocity (how fast (or hardly) was key pressed). And then you can repeat this procedure.

Note that for some messages, like Pitch Wheel Change, two data bytes carry one value (MSB and LSB).

It might be useful to you to know that when the byte starts with 0, it is MIDI data byte. MIDI events have 1 in their first byte.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful resource: http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt

Specifically, you might want to check out the section on the MIDI protocol messages: http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midispec.htm

Beyond that, parsing MIDI is a matter of just walking through the bytes and handling the messages accordingly.

Comment: “Beyond that, parsing MIDI is a matter of just walking through the bytes and handling the messages accordingly.” —— No kidding!

Comment: @Olivier'Ölbaum'Scherler ha, yeah, I know, it makes it sound easier than it is. But MIDI isn't so bad once you get used to it, IMHO. :)

Comment: Yes, it will be interesting. Furst you realise that you can have several packets per message, then that there can be runnning statuses, and then interleaved system messages. :)